# R: Assigned data `*vtmp*` must be compatible with existing data error

Tags: r

I'm new to R with experience in other typical languages and having trouble with creating some functions. I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Assigned data `*vtmp*` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 5114 rows.
x Assigned data has 0 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled
```

Here is the code. Any one know how to fix this?

```
print("***********************************************************************************")
#Load the packages
library(descr)
library(Hmisc)
library(ggplot2)
#Load AddHealthIV Dataset
data<-addhealth4
########################Functions########################################
missingDatatoNA <- function(variable, Missing) {
  for(i in 0:3){
    data$variable[data$variable==3]<-NA
  }
    return(data$variable)
}
####################Explanatory Variables################################
#o = openness to experience, c = conscientiousness, a = etc.
#will eventually make a master secondary variable for each trait
#* indicates necessity for reversal of codes
data$e1<-data$H4PE1 #*
data$e1<-missingDatatoNA(data$e1, c(6,8,"."))
```

Here is the link to the data set:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wTtvsilxR9-RjPPVEFg_tgbBc8MTeG6i/view?usp=sharing

It's from my psych stats class, you can trust it, I don't know how else to safely share it.

Comment: We can't help without more information. Could we please have a [mcve]? (We know it's not convenient to share a data set with 5000+ rows; you can figure out how to make a subset that still demonstrates the problem.)

Comment: @BenBolker I updated the post with the full code and the link to the data set. This is a little more than minimal but should be reproducible.

Comment: As you pass a vector `data$e1` to your function there is no need for `data$variable`. Actually `data$variable` is `NULL`. Simply do `variable[variable==3] <- NA` and of course `return(variable)`.

Comment: @stefan, if you have  a solution please post it as an answer rather than a comment ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pass a vector `data$e1` to your function there is no need for `data$variable`. Actually `data$variable` is `NULL` as there is (probably) no column with name `variable` in your dataset `data`. That's why you get the error.

This could be illustrated using `mtcars` as example data which besides some warnings results in the same error message you reported:

```r
# Reproduce the issue
data <- tibble::as_tibble(mtcars)

missingDatatoNA <- function(variable, Missing) {
  for (i in 0:3) {
    data$variable[data$variable == 3] <- NA
  }
  return(data$variable)
}
data$e1 <- data$hp
missingDatatoNA(data$e1, c(6, 8, "."))
#> Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: `variable`.

#> Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: `variable`.
#> Error: Assigned data `*vtmp*` must be compatible with existing data.
#> x Existing data has 32 rows.
#> x Assigned data has 0 rows.
#> ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
```

To fix your issue could simply do `variable[variable==3] <- NA`:

```r
# Solve the issue
missingDatatoNA_fixed <- function(variable, Missing) {
  for (i in 0:3) {
    variable[variable == 3] <- NA
  }
  return(variable)
}
missingDatatoNA_fixed(data$e1, c(6, 8, "."))
#>  [1] 110 110  93 110 175 105 245  62  95 123 123 180 180 180 205 215 230  66  52
#> [20]  65  97 150 150 245 175  66  91 113 264 175 335 109
```

Comment: Ahh okay, that makes perfect sense. Thanks!